# How to get previous and next six months data from current Date using ajax and MVC controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have tried to use paged list as follows, but it is not possible.

```
var Rank = db.Rankings.Where(a => a.KeywordID == item.KeywordID).OrderBy(a => a.Date).ToPagedList(Month?? 1, 6);
```

Comment: You need to filter the dates in the `.Where()` clause for example `.Where(a => a.Date > someDate && a.Date < anotherDate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.

```
 var lowerlimit = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);
 var upperlimit = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6);
 var rank =db.rankings.Where(a=>a.Date>lowerlimit && a.Date<upperlimit).ToList();
```

I have no idea how to do this using Ajax.